# Why does type-testing in an "if" statement bleed scope, but type-testing in a "switch" statement does not?

Tags: c#, if-statement, types, casting, switch-statement

In the following example methods, `object o` is type-tested using both a `switch` statement and an `if` statement. The methods are functionally identical. However, the `if` statement does not allow one to re-use the same variable name `x` when casting `object o`.

Why does the `switch` statement allow this, but the `if` statement does not?

```
public sealed class Test
{
    public long GetLengthA(object o)
    {
        switch (o)
        {
            case Stream x:
                {
                    return x.Length;
                }
            case Array x: // <-- this is allowed
                {
                    return x.Length;
                }
        }
        return 0;
    }
    public long GetLengthB(object o)
    {
        if (o is Stream x)
        {
            return x.Length;
        }
        else if (o is Array x) // <-- this is NOT allowed
        {
            return x.Length;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

> Error CS0136: A local or parameter named 'x' cannot be declared in this
> scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define
> a local or parameter

[image]

Comment: does this help? https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/proposals/csharp-7.0/pattern-matching.md#scope-of-pattern-variables

Comment: In one word: scope.  In the code that you provided, the reason it is allowed to declare the same variable in the switch statement is because the 'x' is in a different case block inside the switch statement.  Each 'case' block creates a new scope for the pattern-matching variable.  That is not the case with the 'if' statement.  The variable that you are trying to create is using the 'method scope' or the outer scope.

Answer (score 1):

Basically in switch-case, every case is considered as it's own scope/block so you can reuse the variable names but with if-else ladder entire function is the scope/block so you can't really reuse the name. try changing the second variable x to y or something else.

see here,
https://dotnetfiddle.net/LFyxXS

Answer (score 1):

This is basically because the scope of the variable defined in an if statement does extend beyond the if test.

This code is valid (but see below):

```
    public long GetLengthB(object o)
    {
        if (o is Stream x)
        {
            return x.Length;
        }
        
        return x.Length * 2;
    }
```

`x` is valid after the end of the scope, *however* it cannot be used like this, because the compiler will complain that it is undefined, as it is not initialized in case the condition is false. This might sound silly at first, but if you inverse the condition, it now makes sense:

```
    public long GetLengthB(object o)
    {
        if (!(o is Stream x))
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException(...);
        }
        
        return x.Length;
    }
```